# How to change position for a div who has class card

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

I am developing a website for online purchase.

i want my div down a little down for which aye the same positioning as any other class card div.

here is an image to better understand:

[image]

How can you see the div that contains the "yopro" and a little up not like the first.

here is my html code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Bougrine Shop - Home</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/Fevicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/nice-select/nice-select.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Css_acceuil_marjane.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!--================ Start Header Menu Area =================-->
    <header class="header_area">
    <div class="main_menu">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand logo_h" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Bougrine</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false">Shop</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="category.html">Shop Category</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="single-product.html">Product Details</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="checkout.html">Product Checkout</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="confirmation.html">Confirmation</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
                            </li>
               <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tracking-order.html">Tracking</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav-shop">
              <li class="nav-item"><button><i class="ti-search"></i></button></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><button><i class="ti-shopping-cart"></i><span class="nav-shop__circle">3</span></button> </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="button button-header" href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
    <!--================ End Header Menu Area =================-->

  <main class="site-main">

    <!--================ Hero banner start =================-->
    <section class="hero-banner">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center pt-60px">
          <div class="col-5 d-none d-sm-block">
            <div class="hero-banner__img">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="img/marjane.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1 pl-4 pl-md-5 pl-lg-0">
            <div class="hero-banner__content">
              <h4>Shop is fun</h4>
              <h1>Parcourer tout les produits de marjane sur cette page !</h1>
              <p>Notre site est là pour vous aidez a faire vos courses sur tout les grandes surfaces du maroc alors profitez de nos belles offres !</p>
              <a class="button button-hero" href="#">Browse Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--------------- all produit ------------>

    <section id="section_all_produit">
        <h1 id="h1_all_product">Voici tout les produits dans dispose notre magasin "Marjane"</h1>
        <div class="card cardcss" style="width: 18rem; height: 500px;">
            <img src="img/perli.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Perly</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Quantité : 90g</p>
                <p class="card-text">Marques : Jaouda</p>
                <p class="card-text">Lieux de fabrication: Taroudant</p>

                <h3 class="prix" >Prix : 2.5 Dhs</h3>
                <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-achat"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; height: 530px;" id="card2">
            <img src="img/yopro.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Yopro</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Quantité : 90g</p>
                <p class="card-text">Marques : Jaouda</p>
                <p class="card-text">Lieux de fabrication: Taroudant</p>

                <h3 class="prix">Prix : 2.5 Dhs</h3>
                <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-achat"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



  <!--================ Start footer Area  =================-->  
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row section_gap">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget tp_widgets">
                            <h4 class="footer_title large_title">Notre mission</h4>
                            <p>
                                Notre mission c'est de vous satisfere et de rendre vos courses beaucoup plus facile grace à notre site, plus besoin d'allez jusqu'à une grande surface pour faire vos courses, vous pouvez le faire ici sur notre site d'une manière assez facile !.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget tp_widgets">
                            <h4 class="footer_title">Quick Links</h4>
                            <ul class="list">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Brand</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget instafeed">
                            <h4 class="footer_title">Gallery</h4>
                            <ul class="list instafeed d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r5.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r7.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r8.jpg" alt=""></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget tp_widgets">
                            <h4 class="footer_title">Contact Us</h4>
                            <div class="ml-40">
                                <p class="sm-head">
                                    <span class="fa fa-location-arrow"></span>
                                    Notre position
                                </p>
                                <p>Temara, hay el wifaq</p>

                                <p class="sm-head">
                                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                                    Numéro de téléphone
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    (+212) 06 33 26 39 43 <br>

                                </p>

                                <p class="sm-head">
                                    <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                                    Notre email
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    nawfalbougrine@outlook.fr <br>

                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row d-flex">
                    <p class="col-lg-12 footer-text text-center">
                        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Droit d'auteur appartient à Mr.Nawfel Bougrine <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--================ End footer Area  =================-->



  <script src="vendors/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/skrollr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/nice-select/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/mail-script.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my css code:

```
  #h1_all_product {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2a2b75;

}

.prix{
    color: red;
    font-size: 150%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 65px;
}

.btn-achat{

    margin-bottom: 30px; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#card2{


    display: inline-block;
}


.cardcss{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Seems like the images are causing the problem, you need to limit the images size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your images a fixed height and percentage width, and use `object-fit: cover` and `object-position:center`. Something like this:

```
img.card-img-top {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```css
#h1_all_product {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2a2b75;
}

.prix {
  color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 65px;
}

.btn-achat {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#card2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cardcss {
  display: inline-block;
}

img.card-img-top {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="section_all_produit">
  <h1 id="h1_all_product">Voici tout les produits dans dispose notre magasin "Marjane"</h1>

  <div class="card cardcss">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/600" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Perly</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Quantité : 90g</p>
      <p class="card-text">Marques : Jaouda</p>
      <p class="card-text">Lieux de fabrication: Taroudant</p>

      <h3 class="prix">Prix : 2.5 Dhs</h3>
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-achat"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" id="card2">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/550" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Yopro</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Quantité : 90g</p>
      <p class="card-text">Marques : Jaouda</p>
      <p class="card-text">Lieux de fabrication: Taroudant</p>
      <h3 class="prix">Prix : 2.5 Dhs</h3>
      <button href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-achat"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```